# Heavier riders on bike trainers?

Tags: trainer, turbo-trainer, clydesdale

I'm **300-350 pounds** (136-158 kg). Is this **too heavy for trainers such as a Tacx Neo or Wahoo Kickr**? Their specifications say 250-275 pounds, so I'm interested in options for heavier riders.

Comment: Edited to make it less an opinion or shopping question. @PizzaAndCode is encouraged to take the [tour].

Comment: Wattbike is rated to 150kg, and has similar functionality to a Neo/Kickr

Comment: Not a direct answer, but have you considered riding road or trail until you're within the supported weight range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trainers that clip onto your rear wheel aren’t a good option if you’re over their weight limits. They support much of your weight on your rear axle quick release and this can put a lot of stress on components that aren’t designed for this type of static loading. If your bike breaks or the trainer breaks, you don’t have any grounds for a warranty claim or a liability claim if you hurt yourself.

A stationery bike is a much better option as they’re often built more sturdily. Check on Craigslist, they’re often quite cheap especially in the spring when people are clearing out their garages.

Or, go bike outside. There’s almost no unbikeable weather, even Minnesota in the winter — or Minnesota in the summer. (Wink)

Comment: Fellow Minnesotan eh? Step 1: Start biking outside + some choice of diet. Step 2: bike online :)

Answer (score 1):

How about rollers? If you already own a bike that is suitable for you, then this lets you use the same bike.

[image: https://www.cascadebiketrainers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/rollers-side.jpg]

Note that rollers to tend to wear tyres differently to the road, so you may want to fit a set of super-cheap tyres or even get the last wear out of an old tyre.

Comment: Source for the part about tire wear? The common wisdom is that turbo trainer is the one that destroys tires.

Comment: @OJS you're right - a turbo trainer that uses the bike's rear tyre to push a resistance roller would also cause wear.   A turbo trainer would be more "squared-off" wear compared to the road which more rounded wear.  A set of rollers would have wear characteristic somewhere between the two.

Comment: @ojs It very much depends on the tyre/roller combination for the turbo.  I've seen a GP4000/Elite combo destroy a tyre in 1 session, but on the other hand i've seen a Rubino/Cyclops last years on the same tyre with no apparent wear at all.

Comment: @AndyP this is why I wrote "common wisdom", not "fact". The point here was tire wear on rollers compared to turbo trainer, and I would guess the Rubino would also last long on rollers.

Comment: I thought of rollers and didn’t put them in my answer and I assume the OP is a newly, and if they are close to the weight limit for their bike, they could easily taco their wheels falling over on rollers.

Comment: Thank you @Criggie and RoboKaren, as both of your responses provide ideas for going forward. My initial question was truly limited in scope. Criggie thought outside my box :)